# cmake and dll/lib link on Windows

Tags: c, windows, dll, cmake, mingw-w64

I am working on windows with mingw and CMake.

Someone provide a library with lib, dll and header files. I am able to use it quite easily in Visual Studio projects. But I was not able to integrate it into a CMake project. There are already a lot of questions about this topic but only working for Linux, or with library build with CMake, or library where sources are available, or the same use case as me but with a lot of erratum in comments saying that the answer is never completely correct...

I would like to use the **foo_function** from the **foo** library in my **bar** project. I don't have the source of this **foo** project. Only a dll, lib and header file.

```
BarProject
           ├───       
           ├─── CMakeLists.txt  
           ├─── Foo
                          ├─── include       
                                  └─── foo.h
                          ├─── x64        
                                 |─── foo.dll
                                 └─── foo.lib
           └─── main_bar.c
```

This is the content of my **CmakeLists.txt file** :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
# set the project name and version
project(bar VERSION 1.0)

# add the executable
add_executable(bar main_bar.c)

target_include_directories(bar PUBLIC "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}" "foo/include")

add_library(foo SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY
             IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Foo/x64/foo.dll")
set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY
             IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Foo/x64/foo.lib")
target_link_libraries(bar PRIVATE foo)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
set(CMAKE_SUPPRESS_REGENERATION true)

set_property(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY VS_STARTUP_PROJECT bar)
```

Finally to test my work :

```
        $ ls
        main_bar.c CMakeLists.txt Foo
        $ mkdir tutu
        $ cd tutu
        $ cmake .. && cmake  --build . -v
        -- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
        -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19044.
        -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30145.0
        -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30145.0
        -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
        -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
        -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
        (...)
  cl /c /IC:\Users\lambe\work\repository\bar\tutu /IC:\Users\lambe\work\repository\bar\. /IC:\Users\lambe\work\repository\bar\Foo\include/Wall /WX /diagnostics:column /Od /D _MBCS /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D STAND_ALONE /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /Gm- /MD /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"bar.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"bar.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /external:W4 /Gd /TC /wd4996 /wd4820 /wd5045 /wd4668 /errorReport:queue C:\Users\lambe\work\repository\bar\main_bar.c
      main_bar.c
      Generating Code...
    Link:
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"C:\Users\lambe\work\repository\bar\tutu\Debug\bar.exe" /INCREMENTAL /ILK:"bar.dir\Debug\bar.ilk" /NOLOGO ..\Foo\x64\foo.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"C:/Users/lambe/work/repository/bar/tutu/Debug/bar.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"C:/Users/lambe/work/repository/bar/tutu/Debug/bar.lib" /MACHINE:X64  /machine:x64 bar.dir\Debug\main_bar.obj
      bar.dir\Debug\main_bar.obj
    
        main_bar.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol foo_function referenced in function main [C:\Users\lambe\work\repository\bar\tutu\bar.vcxproj]
        C:\Users\lambe\work\repository\bar\tutu\Debug\bar.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [C:\Users\lambe\work\repository\bar\tutu\bar.vcxproj]
```

The compilation step is working great, the issue is during the linking step.

EDIT:

Ok after the comment from Ben Voigt, I choose to explore the solution to use the gcc/g++ compiler from mingw instead of using the CL/Visual Studio thing.

The new test procedure :

```
$ cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles" && cmake --build . -v
(...)
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DSTAND_ALONE @CMakeFiles/bar.dir/includes_C.rsp  -MD -MT CMakeFiles/bar.dir/main_bar.c.obj -MF 

CMakeFiles\bar.dir\main_bar.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\bar.dir\main_bar.c.obj -c C:\Users\lambe\work\repository\bar\main_bar.c
    [100%] Linking C executable bar.exe
    "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\bar.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
    "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E rm -f CMakeFiles\bar.dir/objects.a
    C:\MinGW\bin\ar.exe qc CMakeFiles\bar.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\bar.dir\objects1.rsp
    C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\bar.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -o bar.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libbar.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\bar.dir\linklibs.rsp
    CMakeFiles\bar.dir/objects.a(main_bar.c.obj):main_bar.c:(.text+0x4f4e): undefined reference to `foo_function'
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    CMakeFiles\bar.dir\build.make:830: recipe for target 'bar.exe' failed
    mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [bar.exe] Error 1
    mingw32-make.exe[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/lambe/work/repository/bar/test'
    CMakeFiles\Makefile2:81: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/bar.dir/all' failed
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/bar.dir/all] Error 2
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/lambe/work/repository/bar/test'
    Makefile:89: recipe for target 'all' failed
    mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
```

Ok the result is the same but at least, the command line and tools are more familiar for me.
I cannot find any reference to the foo library in the command line. Then I check the file linklibs.rsp and here we are :

```
$ cat CMakeFiles/bar.dir/linklibs.rsp
 -lm *Foo/x64/foo.lib* -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
```

Is it the expected result?

Comment: Does the `cmake --build ...` output show the command that is executed before you get the error message referring to `main_bar.obj`? If yes, add this to the output in the question.

Comment: Your first sentence says you're compiling with `mingw` but your log indicates you're using the Visual Studio compiler and linker.  Please clarify what tools are used for what pieces (very important since mingw doesn't use Microsoft-format import libraries)

Comment: @Bodo I just updated the output to add the last command executed.

Comment: @BenVoigt I am a Linux guy, I am a beginner with Windows building tool/env. My goal is to be able to compile my binary with command line and cmake in linux and windows env. For windows I am in a git bash/min gw env. I dont know how to select compiler in cmake. There is a way to use the gcc.exe from mingw instead of clang/vs by using a command in the CmakeList file ?

Comment: Does your `foo.h` have either declspec(dllexport) and declspec(dllimport) active depending on whether you are building or consuming the DLL ?  I would expect to see `__imp_foo_function` rather than `_foo_function` in the error message, if the header file is correctly set up.

Comment: I don't use the declsspec feature. I am able to run my bar project in Visual Studio project without it so I was expecting the same behavior from CMake.  Is it a correct statement?

Comment: "I am able to run my bar project in Visual Studio project without it so I was expecting the same behavior from CMake. Is it a correct statement?" - Yes, this is correct expectation. Would you code into `CMakeLists.txt` the same things as you have setup in the successful Visual Studio project, then the CMake project will be compiled successfully too. But we don't know how you setup your Visual Studio project, so we cannot help you with the CMake project.

Comment: I don't know how Visual studio engine is working. But basically, I just put my library in **Additionnal library directories** in linker property and it was working on the first try :(. I am not very familiar with windows compilation line but we can see that my lib file seems to be linked to my main_bar file at the end. I will try to study the possibility to use another compiler from the cl/vs one

Comment: I just update the initial message. I am trying to use the gcc from mingw instead of CL/VS tools @BenVoigt

Comment: I have a minimal example at https://github.com/brechtsanders/ci-test of a library that can be built both static and shared and it can be built on Windows, Linux and macOS and works with both gcc and clang.

Comment: With gcc you want to see the DLL filename on the link command line (in the response file is ok, that's treated as command-line arguments) since Microsoft-format import libraries aren't compatible with gcc, but gcc's linker does know how to read the export table found inside the DLL.